# Archive recovery in xcode?

Tags: xcode

I recently used a system tool which removes 'junk' files to free space up. It deleted every single photo on my hard drive... My xcode code is present for an application I have but can I recover the lost app photos from an xcode archive which still exists? Many thanks, as I can't update my app anymore because of it.

Comment: Unfortunately everyone goes through this at least once on the road to learning to backup your drives. Future: Get a HD and set it up for TimeMachine. For development use GIT and a remote repository, [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/plans) is free.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the ipa that is a zip file, change the extension from .ipa to .zip and double-click to unzip.

That will produce a folder named Payload and in that folder is the app.

The app is a is a package, right click on it and "Show Package Contents".

All your images in the app will be there.

Additionally, if the images were added as Assets there will be an additional step to extract the images form the Assets.car file. See this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28312743/451475) for extraction information.

Comment: This doesn't reveal any photos and I can't get the ipa file as I transferred it badly from another iOS team..

Comment: If the app is in the app store, download it with iTunes and you will have the ipa.

Comment: If the images were added as Assets there will be an additional step to extract the images form the Assets.car file. To extract images from an Assets.car file see this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28312743/451475).

Comment: Hey, um how do I use cartool @Zaph ? I have been meddling with it for ages

Comment: See the link in the answer. You actually have to download the project, build and run it. Read the code in `main.c` and the help: "Usage: cartool Assets.car outputDirectory" I have run it, it did work.