# Assets .car is significantly larger then my png xcassets? Also iPad pro?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Ok so I am having some file size issues with my app! And I don't understand why!

My xcassets folder is 20mb, however the assets.car is almost 60mb! I don't know why Xcode would endeavor to increase a file size... maybe it thinks its optimizing their size?

Any ideas of what I can do to fix this problem? Is there some build setting I should look into?

Changing the bit amount is not an option for me.  All of my assets have transparency and have gradients that need to stay accurate.

I have seen [other topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463935/assets-car-is-6-times-larger-than-actual-images-xcassets-folder-when-archived) on this however they cover dealing with files like jpeg, not pngs->pngs.

Also I am curious considering the new iPad pro's vastly larger screen... how do we provide assets for it?  I don't want iPad Air Retinas running the same assets as the iPad pro because they would be rather huge! I thought maybe in xcassets their would be a 1x and 2x and 3x option... but I can't find that!  How are we supposed to deal with that?

Comment: Did you try looking at the PNG sizes in the generated assets? This might help you understand what is going on. It is possible to extract the PNG images from the assets after creating the full build. Make the app build in the normal way and then examine the generated app and use a tool to extract the assets from the .car. You can then see the resulting PNGs after they have been run through the Xcode PNG optimization tools. It is also possible to simply turn off PNG optimizations in Xcode, that might give you the size results you expect.